# Editing the contents of just one div on a page from wordpress

Tags: php, content

On the homepage of the design I am integrating into Wordpress, this little area (as highlighted in the attached screenshot) needs to be editable for the client to update whenever needed, now this is literally the only piece needed to be editable on the homepage, so I didn't think you'd need to create an entire page for the contents of this div, I however am unsure what's the normal/best approach to make this editable.

[image]

Suggestions welcome. Thanks.

*My first Wordpress integration.

Comment: you can use WP Category list or simply add a loop to show the last post (Yes, insert there a blogpost) also you can use Custom Post Type plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WordPress development!  It is a fantastic content management system.

The normal way to display content for a particular page, on that page, is to use the WP function `the_content();`.  This normally entails creating a simple WP loop to check for the existence of content, then perform certain actions (like creating the HTML to display said content).

WordPress Codex is your best reference for this [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content)

... and for writing a basic WP [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Good luck!